# Should I say "what does it means" or "what does it mean"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, do-support

Sometimes, especially on this forum, I am wondering wether I should say "what does it mean" or "what does it means" ?
And should I say "it means that..." or "it mean that..." ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are the relevant rules:

1. A clause never has more than **one** *finite* verb - a verb that is marked for tense, person and number (to the extent that it *can* be marked for any of these categories.
2. When the verb (predicator) in a finite clause is constructed with auxiliaries (helping verbs), the finite verb is always the **first** auxiliary in the chain.
3. Each auxiliary verb licenses specific non-finite forms (present or past participle or infinitive) for the following non-finite. For instance *BE* licenses either a present or past participle, *HAVE* licenses a past participle, and so forth. Auxiliary *DO* licenses only an infinitive.
4. In questions, the subject and the first, finite auxiliary switch places; if there is no auxiliary, the ‘dummy’ auxiliary *DO* is introduced (this is called *DO-support'), and takes the appropriate finite form.

Consequently:

- In your question, *DO-support* is invoked to provide an invertible finite auxiliary, *does*. It must be followed (after the subject) by the infinitive form of the lexical verb *MEAN*:

  > What does it ***mean***?
- In your answer, *DO-support* is not required; *MEAN* is the only verb and takes the finite form which bears the desired tense (present) and agrees with the subject in person (3d) and number (singular)—*means*.

  > It ***means*** that ...

Answer (score 3):

"What does it mean" and "it means that" is the proper grammar.

Answer (score 1):

You need subject-verb agreement.

What does it mean?

*It* is the logical subject (it does mean what), and *does* is the conjugated verb, so it does (mean), does with an S.

It means that...

*It* is the subject, so *means* with an S.