# How common is "What does XYZ mean*s*"?

Tags: grammaticality, slang, verb-usage

Recently I've noticed that quite a few native English speakers ask like "What does XYZ mean**s**?" instead of "What does XYZ mean?" (There's an `s` at the end)

I know [this is unacceptable in formal English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27120/8629), so I initially thought it was an outright typo. But I feel I keep seeing native English speakers use this pattern too often for a simple typo — maybe once a week or so, on Japanese Language Stack Exchange. (Here's the [search results for `what means`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20means))

My question: "What does XYZ mean**s**?", "What does he say**s**?", and so on... Are these really simple typing mistakes? Or are they actually used as slang, dialect, etc? Is this usage increasing somewhere?

<sub>PS: I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. It's really hard to search for a duplicate of this with the search box :-)</sub>

Comment: They're mistakes.  How do you know that the people writing it are native English speakers?

Comment: I can only guess. But if this is nothing but a mistake, that's fine to me, maybe I was overthinking about this.

Comment: I have never seen a native speaker say this. Those are most probably non-native speakers. It's a common mistake among learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either deliberately "wrong" English as slang (for humorous effect) or dialect.  There are some English dialects that don't conjugate the verb in a "standard" way, but these are usually spoken not written.

Alternately these might simply be misspellings or laziness. Most of the questions in your search use the construction "what means X?" which is a kind of slang-y *inversion* of the expression:

> X means what?

Note this also is not "formal" English, but I don't think it's considered wrong.  The expression "what means X?" is a kind of "baby-talk", though, used to indicate a low level of development or intelligence (like "give cookie!" or "Mommy slow!"), so someone might think it sounds funny to speak that way.

Curious that it shows up on the Japanese language SE though.  It could be these are not native English speakers who are also learning Japanese.

My guess is that, if it is slang, it's a passing fad and not something you would emulate.  For example, there is a "I can haz cheeseburger?" [website](http://icanhas.cheezburger.com/) that, some years ago, really started the whole ["lolcat" and "lolspeak"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lolcat) fad.  But if you see a funny picture with the caption ["Im in ur foldur keruptin yr fylez"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lolcat#/media/File:Lolcat_in_folder.jpg) you know this is not meant to be "good" English but just a humorous interpretation of how cats would talk, if they did talk.